# Spacing preceding a subscript?

Tags: spacing, subscripts

In a document I'm writing, I have a line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\operatorname{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z}/(r),B)= _rB\simeq\cdots
\end{document}
```

However, the subscripted `r` becomes a subscript behind the `=` but I want it to be a subscript preceding the `B`, with a space between that and the `=`. I changed it to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\operatorname{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z}/(r),B)=\ _rB\simeq\cdots
\end{document}
```

by putting a `\` after the `=` to force a split, but of course it introduces an extra space which looks unusual. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to say `{}_rB\simeq` or the subscript would be to the equals sign.

Answer (score 5):

TeX ignores spaces in math mode. Typing (in math mode)

```
=_r
```

or

```
= _r
```

is the same and it results in a subscript to the equals sign. In order to have “presubscripts”, you have to fool TeX into thinking that you want a subscript to an empty object; this is achieved with `{}_{r}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Tor_{1}(\Z/(r),B)= {}_{r}B\simeq\cdots
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how easier it is to get a “Tor” operator, and also the symbol for the integers. An indirect definition is used in order to be able, if need arises, to change *all* number set symbols by modifying `\numberset`, rather than all symbols.